# Application of Jordan–Hölder theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, applications

Jordan–Hölder theorem can be used to prove the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. But I can only prove the uniqueness part of the theorem with Jordan–Hölder theorem. That every composite number is expressible as a product of primes cant be proved. So how can I complete my proof?

Comment: I assume that you are applying Jordan-Holder to $\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$?  Since the theorem gives that the factors of the composition series are unique, all you have to do is show that they are of the form $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ for $p$ prime.  But assume that some factor is not irreducible.  What happens?

Comment: This follows almost by definition of composite, not from the Jordan Holder Theorem. If $n$ is composite, then $n = n_1 n_2$. Then check whether each of $n_1, n_2$ are prime.